# My deployed site looks different than than local version

Tags: reactjs, firebase, deployment

I have a Firebase project that I just deployed. The links on the navbar aren't visible on the deployed version.  This is how is looks locally:

[image: local version of website]

This is what it looks like deployed to my domain:

[image: deployed version of website]

The link is there are the deployed version, and it works when clicked. But why isn't the text black?

The problem is the same when the screen width decreases.  The hamburger shows up on both. On the local version, when clicking on the hamburger, the drop-down with the links is visible.  On the deployed version, the drop-down links are not visible.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.  I had set the opacity of the element containing the link as `opacity: 85%`.  This works fine locally, so I didn't notice there was an issue.  However, in the deployed code, the opacity was changed to `opacity: 1%`.  When I changed the setting to `opacity: 0.85` the deployed code worked as expected.

Lesson learned - always set opacity using a decimal.  Weird that setting it as a percentage worked locally, though.